# Filtering by ALL or by selected attribute

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

Excuse my language or SQL/Reporting wording

I am generating a report using Reporting Services where I have 2 drop down lists in order to show only by period and by category. I want it so if I select  and  I am shown all entries and if selected from any of the 2 drop downs then filter by those selections. I have a stored procedure which states the following on it's WHERE clause:

```
WHERE (dbo.PERIOD_LIST.PERIOD_DESC = @period) OR (dbo.CATEGORY.CATEGORY_DESC = @category)
```

However I cannot get this to work on Reporting Services/Visual Studio. I am shown ALL the entries instead of the filtered ones. I initialize @period and @category as NULL. So how can I make it so the report shows all rows when both attributes are null and still be able to filter by each or both of them?

How can I achieve this?

**Edit: I used the suggestion Filip Popović gave me. If you're having this problem modify your prepared statement and make sure you refresh fields on your data sets since there's additional clauses on your prepared statement!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in SQL, NULL = NULL is never evaluated to true. You can take it as NULL is not nothing it is something but unspecified. And You can't compare two unspecified values. You have to test COL1 IS NULL to get true if column has null value.

Try this:

```
WHERE ((dbo.PERIOD_LIST.PERIOD_DESC = @period) OR (@period IS NULL))
AND ((dbo.CATEGORY.CATEGORY_DESC = @category) OR (@category IS NULL))
```

Comment: Procedure works but for some reason it doesn't display on visual studio on RDL design.

Comment: You are welcome. Please edit your question and write how You solved if there was some problem not mentioned in this thread :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameter for NULL as part of the condition:

```
WHERE ((@period IS NULL) OR (dbo.PERIOD_LIST.PERIOD_DESC = @period))
  AND ((@category IS NULL) OR (dbo.CATEGORY.CATEGORY_DESC = @category))
```